# IBM Worklight - How to pass parameters/requests to the WebView from Native

Tags: android, webview, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a service that receives messages from a PHP server and then raises a notification.
I am trying to access the Worklight WebView from Native when the notification is tapped.

Currently I am passing the requests through the URL HashTag by restarting the Worklight activity. Then, in the init() function I check the hashtag and follow accordingly.

I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do that, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hello');")
```

or, assuming you have a function called doSomething() in javascript:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:doSomething()");
```

---

I am not sure this is what you had in mind, but
A way to pass parameters from a native page to the webview is by using the [WL.NativePage API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_accessing_native_pages_on_mobi.html).

You can [read about the concept](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova) as well as check out a sample app.
Specifically, take a look at "Android – Using native pages in hybrid applications".

Comment: WL.NativePage only helps me when i'm in the WL webview, and calls the function from there. in my case i start from the service so i cant use it directly

Comment: thanku @Idan Adar, the loadurl(javascript:doSomething() was what i was looking for. I know it's not the best way to work with worklight but for what i was trying to do it did the job :>

Comment: Great. :) Please mark as answered if it meets your satisfaction!